# Shimano Inter-3 Hub coaster brake maintainance

Tags: brakes

When I brake with my Shimano Inter-3 hub coaster brake it makes a loud screaming sound. There is an indication on the hub where you should lubricate it but I do not get it, there is no hole/opening to the hub. Can anybody point me at the right direction? Do I really have to open the entire hub?

I tried to lubricate it with normal chain oil from the outside (I know it's not the right one) but had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One I dealt with, I think a 3C40, that came in with a complaint of squealing while braking turned out to have had broken chunks coming off the part known in the Shimano exploded drawings as the "Driver Unit", which was replaceable. Based on that I recommend just opening it up, ideally after getting some of the Shimano internal hub grease. It's a little fiddly but not very technical, and Shimano's instructions are good. If you really want to try to address it with minimal disassembly, you could probably get some grease to reach the pads by taking off the left side locknut and cone/reaction arm. The pads reside just a little further in on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

In order to grease the brake shoes you will need to disassemble the hub. It is not impossible at home, but most choose to have it done at a shop. If you can find the exact model number, there are exploded view diagrams on the web.

If you want to do it yourself, use graphite for the brake parts, because the heat from braking can cook regular grease. For bearings you should use regular grease.